# Distinction between district and street of city

Tags: php, openstreetmap

I have a string which contain City name, street and district:

```
CITY_NAME, STREET, DISTRICT
```

Sometimes it's look like this:

```
STREET, DISTRICT, CITY_NAME.
```

Every time I know the name of city but I don't know the name of district and street.

```
<?php

$city_name = 'Warszawa'; // Warsaw
$string = 'Warszawa, Ursynów, Pileckiego'; // CITY, DISTRICT, STREET
$array = explode(',', $string);

foreach($array AS $key => $value)
{
    if ( trim($value) == $city_name )
    {
        echo 'The key of city name is: '.$key; // The key of city name is: 0
    }
}

?>
```

Finally I know the City name but I don't know which key of array contain district name and which key contain street name.

How I can detect it using OpenStreetMap? (I wouldn't like to use Google Maps).

Comment: If the order in the input changes, it's pretty much impossible to know what is what without a reference (a list of cities, districts and streets)

Comment: @FirstOne we can't check it using OpenStreetMaps? For example if we make query with 'Ursynów' (this is district) as street - we should get 0 results. It's imposible?

Comment: Are those the only two formats for the string? If street is always followed by district then it should be fairly easy to switch the logic based on whether or not the string starts with the city name.

Comment: No, it's random. Sometimes is: city, street, district, sometimes is street, district, city, sometimes is street, city, district etc. But every time I know city name, so my search-values is always only district and street name.

Comment: Not a duplicate but similar question I answered a few months ago. Maybe this method can be used? If you get a list of cities and streetnames then the "rest" should be district. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741810/smarty-php-regex-replace/45743587#45743587